# Is there console.log output support to terminal/command-line with intern-runner?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, phantomjs, intern

I have a dependency with Intern where we have to spin up a Selenium server and use PhantomJS for our tests. We use Jenkins and may need some more inspection/debug output to console but the console.log's get suppressed from the test files to terminal/command-line

Is console.log to terminal/command-line supported yet?

Comment: Would the purpose be to return back stdout to the Jenkins console output?

Comment: yes and also for local development debugging specific to stdout

Comment: When I ran into a similar scenario, I had resorted to writing my logs into a file that was accessible by the Jenkins instance; to which I added an extra build step to read the contents of the file so they are readable from within Jenkins. Not a completely ideal and foolproof plan, but it got the job done.

Comment: thanks for the info. How did you using console.log() from your javascript file to a file where the runner resides?

Answer (score 4):

How `console.log` works with `intern-runner` depends on where your test code is running. Unit tests (specified with `suites`) run in the browser, so that's where `console.log` output ends up. There isn't currently a way to get console output out of a browser for unit tests.

Functional tests (specified with `functionalSuites`) control a browser, but actually run in Node.js, so output from `console.log` statements in functional tests generally goes to intern's stdout. The exceptions are log statements in `execute` and `executeAsync` blocks; since those blocks run in the browser, that's where the log output ends up. You can retrieve browser logs in functional tests using `getLogsFor('browser')`, but WebDriver log support is inconsistent between browsers.

Comment: thanks for the reply @jason0x43. We have a dependency to run our unit tests in a browser context but still need to potentially debug or have more detailed console.logs at the command-line for our CI environment. Since we use phantomjs as a browser configuration, would I be able to use that `getLogsFor('browser')` in the same way to get the output I'm looking for?

Comment: Documentation of the getLogsFor() method: https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/module-leadfoot_Command.html#getLogsFor